# HSQLDialect to MySQL5InnoDBDialect, Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, tomcat, innodb

I've been using HSQLDialect as dialect for my database (MySQL, most of tables as InnoDB) on some projects and I never had any problem with Hibernate.

I encountered *MySQLSyntaxErrorException* when using *setMaxResults()* in a project using Spring 3.1.0 and Hibernate 3.6.9, and I still wonder where does that come from..

My XML config servlet :

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="***************" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/social/admin/beans/DevDebugLogs.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/social/admin/beans/Users.hbm.xml</value>
                ...
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/logs.html" class="com.social.admin.controllers.DebugManagerAdmin"> 
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" /> 
    </bean>
```

I tried to switch from HSQLDialect to MySQL5InnoDBDialect and it destroyed a big part of my database, dropping entries, deleting tables .... !!!!!!! X)

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: "it destroyed a big part of my database, " at startup (`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
`), or by some functions that you have implemented?

Comment: at startup, probably the "create" flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid deleting tables and data, make sure you switch Hibernate in your configuration to `update`:
`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>`

This will help you to get rid of the problems with disappearing data.

Switching to `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` shouldn't cause any major problems. I have been using it for a very long time in every project of mine. The only thing that might happen is the fact, that some queries might not run exactly the same under different dialects, but you will be able to examine it at runtime or during tests.

Comment: Thanks, I'll switch and check if (hopefully) my database survives .